# Some sites do not allow requesting the same file twice

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5, iis-8

I am going to set a download for user, but when I using this code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ".pdf");
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(@"Resumes\" + FileName + ".pdf"));
Response.End();
```

this error will shown:

[image: IDM Error]

and when I use this code:

```
string filename = FileName + ".pdf";
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
string aaa = Server.MapPath("~/Resumes/" + filename);
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Resumes/" + filename));
Response.End();
```

this error will shown:

[image]

when I'm trying to download file with browser, it completely downloads without any error, but IDM shows these errors !!!

I am using asp.net 4.5 and IIS 8

Comment: http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/sites2_2.html suggests that you should try to enable "Start downloading immediately while displaying ..." option in "Options->Downloads" dialog. I wonder if this can somehow help in identifying the source of the problem.

Comment: It could not help me. I can not change IDM settings in all client pcs!!! And I suggest It has this problem with all download managers.

Comment: And I changed my IDM settings, But still I have these errors. I think there is a problem with IIS, because in my pc and localhost, it acts good, but it is not working on the server

Comment: I agree, this sounds like its a combination of how the requests are being made by IDM and how the server is configured to handle those requests. I suspect that the server is issuing a unique session to IDM and it's trying to prevent multiple simultaneous requests. I personally have not had to address an issue like this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code, it seems that it acts good. but I didn't saw this code anywhere in any website for file download, so I am not sure I doing right. anyway it is working!!!

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("http://MySite.com/Resumes/" + FileName + ".pdf");
```